# Using board names as tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Given that the site's focus area is Arduino, creating tags such [arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno) does not seem to me, as ideal. I think that just the board name without Arduino prefixed to it is sufficient, as the Arduino in the name is implicit.

So, should tags be of the form [arduino-boardname](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-boardname) or simply [boardname](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boardname)? Eg, [arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno) vs [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers given (Thanks @Butzke!), I felt it prudent to create a tag list of sorts for all the official boards. Feel free to add any missing board with the desirable tag name. If you disagree with any of the tag names, please mention so in a comment.

- Uno - [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno)
- Leonardo - [leonardo](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo)
- Due - [due](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/due)
- Yún - [yun](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yun)
- Tre - [tre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tre)
- Micro - [arduino-micro](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-micro)
- Robot - [arduino-robot](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-robot)
- Esplora - [esplora](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esplora)
- Mega - [mega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega)
- Ethernet - [arduino-ethernet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-ethernet)
- Mega 2560 - [mega-2560](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega-2560)
- Mini - [arduino-mini](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-mini)
- Arduino Pro - [arduino-pro](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-pro)

All variations of the board name will be synonimized eg. [arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno) will map to [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno). This list is for the tags that will be *visible* to users eg. [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno), once the synonym is established.

Comment: Have all the Lilypads too.

Comment: Its missing the [tag:mini], [tag:nano], [tag:pro-mini], [tag:pro] and [tag:fio]

Comment: @Butzke Feel free to update it.

Comment: Readers should note that this is nothing more than AsheeshR's **personal opinion** - the fact that they accepted their own answer to their own question is not in any way a "decision" by the community of this site, and carries absolutely no weight.

Answer (score 16):

I disagree removing the [arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) before the name of the board.

Exist a [lot of Arduinos](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Products) that could make some troubles in tags, if we put just the name of the Arduino like:

1. Arduino Ethernet
2. Arduino Mini
3. Arduini Micro
4. Arduino Robot
5. Arduino Nano
6. Arduino Pro

Exist many possibilities to have a tag [ethernet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethernet) or [robot](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robot) that don't have anything to do with the Arduino Ethernet or with the Arduino Robot.

Even the Tags [mini](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini), [micro](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro) and [nano](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nano) would be confusing just with this.

I think that putting the word arduino before the name of the board will be more organized.

Comment: Hmmm.  This is a very good point that I hadn't thought of...  +1

Comment: Since this was the highest-voted answer, I've implemented tag synonyms on this basis. Everything is now of the format like: [tag:arduino-uno] and [tag:arduino-mini] etc.

Answer (score 5):

The tags should be named [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno), [mega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega), etc., so long as the board in question is an "official" board.  Using [arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno) would be like a tag called [math-arithmetic](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-arithmetic) on Math.SE.

The [arduino-boardname](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-boardname) tags should be made synonyms, too, for the [boardname](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boardname), in any event.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Butzke that there can be confusion about whether or not the tag means the board. There are even three [ethernet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethernet) questions already. However, it is unlikely that [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno) will be mistaken for anything other than the Uno board. I propose that some boards, such as the Uno, Yún, Duemilanove, and Esplora should have not have `arduino` in the tag name ([arduino-duemilanove](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-duemilanove) can't even exist; it's five chars over the limit), but others, such as Ethernet, Micro, and Robot should.

Comment: arduino-due seems good enough, considering it's the way most people refer to it anyway.

Comment: @ScottM. There are still other names longer than 7 letters.