# Which tags need to be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tags

The initial days of beta can be a little awkward for tags. This post is meant to be a community-wiki style list of tags that need to be cleaned up for cases where users (like me) don't have sufficient reputation to make the changes.

Please feel free to edit my answer and add any changes you see need to be made (or remove any changes that have been completed)

Comment: I went through a lot of these and cherry picked the obvious ones. We don't really create tags and synonyms until an actual use case or problem is demonstrated. For the rest, how to retag individual questions would need a bit more experience from an actual Arduino user, so I'll leave those until pro tem moderators are appointed.

Answer (score 8):

### Irrelevant Tags

These tags are mostly accidentally created and should be removed.

- [c++](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Discussion Here](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/when-should-we-use-the-c-tag)

---

### Vague Tags

These should be removed (maybe even blocked if there is an option in the SE engine) because they are too vague.

- [input](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input) Too vague. The question that uses it uses it fine, but it really doesn't *help* someone find that question, and interrupts should be sufficient.
- [ide](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) should be split into [arduino-ide](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-ide) and individual tags such as [eclipse](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)

---

### Spelling

These tags are mostly ones that need to be separated with a "-".

[None]

---

### Synonyms

Synonyms require significant reputation or moderator abilities to create. The "master tag" (or whatever the proper term is) will replace the synonym when typed.

- [atmega328](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmega328) I don't know what to do about this one really but often people tag this along with [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno)/[arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno)
- <strike>[build](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build) → [compile](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile) Some beginners may tag it as [build](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build) but for the *physical* construction of a project.</strike> Mods have decided to leave it and watch it.

---

### Tags to watch in the future...

Tags for topics that may be deemed off-topic soon.

- [enclosure](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure) Will we allow shopping questions here?

Comment: Sorry, [Severino](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardSerialSingleSided3) is one particular type of Arduino board. Is that tag you are referring to as improperly puncutated?

Comment: Sorry, there is no questions under it yet. So I figured it had to do with this https://github.com/tarekziade/arduino/blob/master/mamacar/server.ino

Comment: No problem. In any case, I would be suspicious about any tags that end with the suffix `.ino` as would probably refer to a sketch somewhere, which may not be worth a tag for it.

Comment: I agree, Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I disagree with this. Over half of the first 20 questions on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ bear almost no relation to electronics. (Yes, I counted)

Comment: I agree with removing [tag:electronics], as it's a very "non-descriptive" tag.  Other tags (e.g. [tag:LED] or [tag:pins]) would make it *obvious* if a question is about electronics or not.  It's *almost* (but not quite) a "meta-tag."

Comment: Um... [tag:programming] is nowhere close to [tag:uploading]...

Comment: @hichris123 Your right... a new user still could confuse them though. I'll try to see what I can do and put a not in the wiki now.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE:** If you do create a edit to this post to edit tags, please comment them out with `<!--TAG CONTENT HERE-->` to preserve it in case we ever need it again. Also, make sure your edit has been approved before commenting out any tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Spelling errors

- [webserver](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webserver) should be [web-server](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-server)
- <s>[r](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) should be [r-environment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r-environment) One letter tags tend to be confusing</s> *Language tags should always be the language name, till the point a conflict arises.*

### Merges

- [uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uno) and [arduino-uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-uno) should be the same ([pending discussion](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/4))
- [due](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/due) with [arduino-due](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-due)
- The [upload](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upload) tag should be merged into the more established [uploading](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uploading) tag.

Comment: Language tags should be simply language names. A person who would use the [tag:R] tag, would know what it is.