# When should we use the C++ tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I've noticed that a new user (who admittedly has **lot** of rep on other SE sites) has been re-tagging some programming questions to include the [c++](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

These are the questions so far:

- [Last element of a struct disappearing on write/read](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/429/last-element-of-a-struct-disappearing)
- [sprintf() to assemble String and float pieces locks up](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/493/sprintf-locks-up-arduino-yun)
- [Is it better to use c_str or toCharArray?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/518/is-it-better-to-use-c-str-or-tochararray)
- [Is it better to use #define or const int for constants?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/506/is-it-better-to-use-define-or-const-int-for-constants)

Given that the vast majority of programming on Arduino is in C++, it seems like a somewhat redundant tag in many cases. With that said, I am sure there are cases where it actually *is* relevant though.

When should we tag with [c++](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and when is the `programming` tag sufficient on its own?

Comment: I approved an edit to my question as it was very specifically about a difference between C and C++.

Comment: @Cybergibbons Likewise, I approved it on my question about c_str and toCharArray, because it relates back to the standard C++ language. I'm not sure about more general cases though.

Answer (score 5):

I think most questions will be fine with just `programming`. However, there are some cases where giving it a `C++` tag would be appropriate:

- When its a question on the C/C++ language. The answer will be in the details on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) or [AVR Libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html) something.
- When it's something that the Arduino language differs from standard C++ since [you can't do everything](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus).

If it's a question about code not working due to logic errors or not knowing how to write something, that's a `programming` question.

Only a handful of questions should be tagged `C` or `C++`.

Answer (score 4):

I usually add the C++ tag when I get the chance for one simple reason:

*It activates syntax-colouring for the code.*

(assuming there is code posted)

It also activates syntax-colouring for any code in replies.

There **is** a way of doing that without the C++ tag, which is to paste this in your question or reply:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-C++ -->
```

Syntax colouring makes the code much more readable, and is useful to have when browsing someone's code in the question, and someone's code in the answer.

By the way, if you have done this and want to post something which is *not* code (like serial monitor output) you can also disable the colouring like this:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
```

Comment: Using a language tag merely for highlighting is a violation of basic SE guidelines - tags should reflect what is a question is *about* rather than what it *contains*.  If people did not abuse the C++ tag for every question that merely happens to contain some C++ code, the issue of this page would not exist, and the tag could properly be used for language questions.  As you point out, there is a correct way to do syntax highlighting - additionally syntax highlighting is hardly essential.  Last I checked the arduino IDE did not even support it :-;

Comment: That was a while ago, right? It would make more sense if SE *automatically* switched on C++ syntax colouring in code in the Arduino section. Newbies won't know about the tag to turn on colouring (nor care, probably). And what other language would code be in?